# How to use strtok in C if delimiter is defined as character

Tags: c, char, c-strings, strtok

I'm trying to use strtok for a school assignment of mine, but the delimiter declared as a constant in the code is declared as a character, and I'm not allowed to change this. This delimiter is supposed to be arbitrary and has to work for any value. When I try to use strtok however, it expects a string. What is a workaround for splitting up strings when the delimiter is strictly defined as a single char in C?

Comment: Use a string with one character.

Answer (score 3):

You can use compound literal for that.

Examples:

```
token = strtok(str, (char[]){'a',0});
```

or

```
const char delim = 'a';

token = strtok(str, (char[]){delim,0});
```

or if you need to use more chars you can define a macro

```
#define MKS(...) ((char[]){__VA_ARGS__, 0})

/* ... */

    token = strtok(str, MKS('a', 'b', 'c', ','));
```

Comment: Nice use of standard features: _compound literal_ and `__VA_ARGS__`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a character constant like for example

```
const char c = ' ';
```

then to use strtok you can declare a character array like

```
char delim[] = { c, '\0' };
```

or that is the same

```
char delim[2] = { c };
```

In fact you can write your own function `strtok` using the character and the function `strchr`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char c = ' ';
    char s[] = "Hello World";

    char *start = s, *end = NULL;
    do
    {
        end = strchr( start, c );
        if ( end != NULL )
        {
            if ( end != start )
            {
                *end = '\0';
                puts( start );
            }

            start = end + 1;
        }
        else if ( *start )
        {
            puts( start );
        }
    } while ( end != NULL );
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: Wouldn't `char delim[] = {c};` automatically null terminate?

Comment: No, that magic only happens for string literals or for arrays initialised with a size larger than the number of elements provided.

Comment: @Irelia no. It will have to be `char delim[2] = {c,};`